# customize printing page with CSS

Tags: html, css, printing

I created a table in my page with about 500 rows,
first row is table head (name, family, email, tel and ...) and another rows are table body.

Now when I trying to print this page in A4 Portrait page, the sum of printed page are about 8 pages.

Is there any way to repeat table head in first of all pages ?
The height of each row is variable so I cannot count the rows.

Comment: If you use `thead` it should do this automatically depending on what browser you're in. Works great in Firefox, not sure about others.

Comment: have you already seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844391/css-repeat-table-header-after-page-break-print-view or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434790/table-heading-repeat-while-printing ?

Comment: @APAD1 I used `thead` and `tbody` but not work in chrome :(

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Thanks I checked that links but not work in chrome

Comment: Use Firefox, apparently it's a known issue in Chrome and since it was first reported in 2009 and still not fixed, I doubt it will be fixed any time soon. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826